# JSON and datatable with struts2

Tags: struts2

i am new in JSON and datatable can anybody tell how can i parse json data from struts2 action class to my jsp page and represent it as a table using datatable?

Comment: You're asking for a datatable tutorial?

Comment: no i am just asking how can i parse json data from my action class and show it on my jsp page using datatable

Comment: You're asking how to deal with JSON in Java?

Comment: yeah!!!something like that only

Comment: Create a Java Bean that represents the correct structure of the expected json result.  Then one possibility is using the Struts json plugin.  You can specify your bean as the root object to serialize http://struts.apache.org/plugins/json/#root-object